# How to make Bottom Navigation Bar visible on every page of my app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bottomnav

Please, anyone, tell me how can I make Bottom Navigation Bar visible on every page of my app in flutter? I know there's an option called Custom Navigator (https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator), but how to use this for more than 2 subpages? Please help me I am stucked on a big project. Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: How do you navigate to the next route? Is it push? Have you tried pushReplacement?

Comment: Okk, I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to change widgets on the same page, not navigating, check this code out!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './pages/home.dart'; //imported widget 1
import './pages/listed_homes.dart'; //imported widget  2
import './widgets/form_card.dart'; //imported widget   3

    class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return BottomNavState();
        }
    }

    class BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
        int _currentIndex = 0; //initialize index that alters widgets when increased or decreased`

        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: _currentIndex,
              onTap: (value) {
                _currentIndex = value;
                setState(() {});
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    //<--- item 1 text and icon declared
                    icon: Icon(Icons.book),
                    title: Text('Find a home')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    //<--- item 2 text and icon declared
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                    title: Text('Enlist a home')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    //<--- item 3 text and icon declared
                    icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                    title: Text('Messages')),
              ]),
           body: Stack(children: [
            [
              Home(_cent), //widget one
              FormCard(widget.model), //widget two
              Messages()  //widget three
            ][_currentIndex], //Alter widgets with changing index
            Positioned(
              top: 30,
              left: 15,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                iconSize: 40.0,
              ),
            )
          ]),
        );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this method to keep a widget on every page:

```
MaterialApp(
 title: 'Flutter Demo',
 initialRoute:"/home",
 routes: [
   ...
 ],
 builder: (context, child) {
 return Stack(
  children: [
    child!,
    Overlay(
      initialEntries: [
        OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) {
            return YourCustomWidget(); *//This widget now appears on all  pages*
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
},
```

Comment: That's a great approach. Thank you so much.